# The position of letter inside the button no is the same that it see in the phone

Tags: css, class-diagram

I have a problem diagramming with CSS. What happens:

I have two files. That one is for responsive.

But sometime or right now i working with one. put one button for close one modal. But this button when i up the file to the github have a position good that happen in responsive  in my cellphone in not right.
i wan to know what happen.

all the files is here.
https://github.com/wilsonromero1/room2
open the folder responsive/ style-index.css
the button is a. cerra this is the class
the index is in the starting

[image: i try all and my cellphone see like this.]

Comment: I tested your files and have a [different result than your image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMm8z.png). Is it possible to make a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: i fixed. I just to did a gange.
Put the arial font in the font-family.

like this.
delte de avan.
and put arial. font-family: arial;

Answer (score 0):

i fix the problem, i change the font family for **Arial**